# Making an API call between two laravel websites

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I'm trying to make an API request between two laravel websites. For the first website, this is how it's structured.

**api.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
  Route::get('getCountries', 'ApiController@getCountries');
});
```

**ApiController**

```
public function getCountries()
    {              
        $country = Country::get();
        $country->makeHidden(['flag']); //svg 
        return $country;
    }
```

This returns on postman using GET https://website.com/api/v1/getCountries:

```
[{"id":1,"iso":"AF","name":"AFGHANISTAN","nicename":"Afghanistan","iso3":"AFG","numcode":4,"phonecode":93,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":2,"iso":"AL","name":"ALBANIA","nicename":"Albania","iso3":"ALB","numcode":8,"phonecode":355,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":3,"iso":"DZ","name":"ALGERIA","nicename":"Algeria","iso3":"DZA","numcode":12,"phonecode":213,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":4,"iso":"AS","name":"AMERICAN SAMOA","nicename":"American Samoa","iso3":"ASM","numcode":16,"phonecode":1684,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":5,"iso":"AD","name":"ANDORRA","nicename":"
```

**On a different website**, calling this API endpoint with this

**web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
Route::get('/test', function () {      

        $response = Http::get('http://website.com/api/v1/getCountries');
        dd($response);
    });
```

gives cURL error 28: Failed to connect to website.com port 80: Connection timed out.

Any idea as how to make an API call between 2 laravel websites? Could it be something related to Auth, Headers or something else?

Comment: Typo? `https://` vs `http://`

Comment: @kerbh0lz thank you for your answer, I've changed it to https but the same issue occurs

Comment: Just to make sure: you do have _two_ webservers running for your two sites? What are those, Apache, nginx, `php artisan serve`? Entering `https://website.com/api/v1/getCountries` in your browser returns the JSON back?

Comment: Yes, two webservers, both Apache (they're actually hosted on the same dedicated server). And yes, pasting the URL does return the JSON data back.

Comment: Some browser addon maybe? uMatrix, uBlock etc.? CORS? Did you check your browser's DevTools Network tab/console for anything unusual?

Comment: Nothing strange, just changed ports because of the change to SSL, cURL error 28: Failed to connect to website.com port 443.

I'm not using any addon that could block this.

Comment: Just tested it on Laravel playground and it seems to work ok, no clue what the problem could be, sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was simply a firewall configuration on the server that didn't allow requests to come from the same place. Hosting opened up the required port and it worked without any issues.